# Querying last two days depending on a Workday or not table

Tags: mysql, sql, average

We use Mysql  and we're trying to get averages from last two workdays from a hourly data set like this.

```
  
Date                Price
2016-12-13 00:00    187,68  
2016-12-13 01:00    201
2016-12-13 02:00    211,66  
2016-12-13 03:00    215,84
```

So we created a table named (Workdays) that shows if the day is a workday or holiday like this:

```
 
Date        Workday
2016-12-13    1
2016-12-14    1
2016-12-15    0 
2016-12-16    0
```

1 means workday and 0 means weekend or National Holiday

At the and, we have to query Average price of the last two workdays seperately considering Workdays table

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why does your table `Workdays` have duplicates?  And is 2016-12-13 really a workday or not?  It has conflicting values.

Comment: You're so right, it is my ver very bad. Sorry. The correct values are: 2016-12-13 1    2016-12-14  1    2016-12-15   0    2016-12-16    0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the table `workdays` really has a single row for each date.  If so, you can get the most recent two workdays in a subquery and then use `join` to choose the rows in the first table:

```
select wd.date, avg(h.Price)
from hourly h join
     (select wd.date
      from workdays wd
      where wd.workday = 1 and wd.date <= curdate() -- you might want <
      order by wd.date desc
      limit 2
     ) wd2
     on date(h.date) = wd.date
group by wd.date;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select W.Date, AVG(Price)
from Prices p
join Workdays W on 
    w.Date = DATE(P.Date) 
    AND Workday=1 
    and W.Date <= curdate()
group by W.Date
order by W.Date desc;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this query does not give an AVG but gives the data at 2016-12-12 00:00. (it is December 13 when we run the query)

Comment: it looks to me the same result of accepted answer but at one third of query cost